# Roles stopped woring in FormsAuthentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, authentication, webforms

After upgrading from .net version 3.5 to 4.5 roles in  `FormsAuthentication` stopped working. The user is authenticated, but the framework doesn't seem to  pick up role information and the user is denied access to admin stuff.

Here's the code that logs in the user:

```
        int timeout = int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["loginTimeoutMinutes"]);

        HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = timeout;

        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            username,
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(timeout),
            false,
            roles,
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

        string hash = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, // Name of auth cookie
            hash); // Hashed ticket

        if (ticket.IsPersistent) cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
```

In Global.asax this code updates the current user with role information. When I debug I can see that the role is admin:

```
    protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.User != null)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated &&
                HttpContext.Current.User.Identity is FormsIdentity)
            {

                FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity) HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
                FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = id.Ticket;

                string userData = ticket.UserData;
                string[] roles = userData.Split(',');
                HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, roles);
            }
        }
    }
```

Here's the authentication bit of the main web.config:

```
  <roleManager enabled="true"></roleManager>
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms name="theForm" loginUrl="/login.aspx"/>
  </authentication>
```

After logging in the user is redirected to a file in a folder with the following `web.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings/>
  <connectionStrings/>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="admin" />
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I debug everything looks fine, but the user is denied access to admin pages.

Have I missed something? Help is appreciated. (I know this question been asked before, but I've read about 50 questions/answers here on stackoverflow and tried all the suggestions without finding the answer)

(Another strange thing is that after upgrading .net version I had to add

```
<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
```

to web.config to get the redirect to go to the correct login page.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good people of Stackoverflow!

I was using the wrong `EventHandler`. The one to use is `PostAuthenticateRequest`.

My sincere apologies to the eighteen persons who read the question and whose time I have wasted.